# Changing the output of xml using xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

How to change the output of the xml.

This is the output that i am getting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">

<Header> </Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
      <Run xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run">

        <RunObject class="entity">
          <A1>NA</A1>
          <A2>False</A2>
          <A3>02</A3>
          <A4>ER</A4>
        </RunObject>

        <RunObject class="entity">
          <A1>NA</A1>
          <A2>False</A2>
          <A3>03</A3>
          <A4>ER</A4>
        </RunObject>

      </Run>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

And the output that i want is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>

  <Header> </Header>
  <Body>
    <Document>

      <Item>
        <A1>NA</A1>
        <A2>False</A2>
        <A3>02</A3>
        <A4>ER</A4>
      </Item>

      <Item>
        <A1>NA</A1>
        <A2>False</A2>
        <A3>03</A3>
        <A4>ER</A4>
      </Item>

    </Document>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I have tried various things but still i am not to make one final change.

I am not able to change `<Runobject class="Entity">` to `<Item>`.

This the xslt code that i used to alter the xml format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

**Removes the run tag along with the namespace
  <xsl:template match="s:Run">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

 **Copies all the tags 
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

**Used this code to replace the <RunObject class="entity"> with <Item> but is not working
  <xsl:template match="RunObject[@class='Entity']">
    <xsl:element name="Item">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>


  **Removes all namespaces
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>



  **Copies attributes
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>

    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>





  <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am fairly new to xslt so i mght have certain mistakes while writing the code

Comment: "I want" is not a question.

Comment: I have made the change, now can you please answer the question.

Comment: I am afraid you are missing the point. This is not a code-writing service. If you have a specific question about some difficulty you encountered when you tried to do this yourself, ask it.

Comment: I have to make around three changes to get the desired xml output. I am able to make two changes but not able to make the third change i.e changing the <runobject class="entity"> to <item>. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Post your current XSLT so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: This xml is being generated by AX 2012 and i am trying to alter it using xslt. So i do not have the code that generated the xml, although i can provide you the xslt code that i used to alter the xml.

Comment: That is what I meant.

Comment: I have posted the xslt ocde that i have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why your template:

```
<xsl:template match="RunObject[@class='Entity']">
    <xsl:element name="Item">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

does not match anything:

1. `RunObject` is in a namespace, and you are not using a prefix;
2. XML is case-sensitive; the `class` attribute contains `"entity"`, not `"Entity"`.

It should work if you do:

```
<xsl:template match="s:RunObject[@class='entity']">
    <xsl:element name="Item">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Other than that, I believe you could shorten the entire thing considerably - say:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run"
exclude-result-prefixes="m r">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- move all elements to no namespace -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- rename MessageParts to Document + skip the Run wrapper -->
<xsl:template match="m:MessageParts">
    <Document>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Run/*"/>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>

<!-- rename RunObject to Item -->
<xsl:template match="r:RunObject[@class='entity']">
    <Item>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Item>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can i change the order of the child nodes as well?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. You can add `xsl:sort` to `xsl:apply-templates`, if you want some logical order.

Comment: But i am unable to rename the parent node and rearrange the child nodes simultaneously. I want to reshuffle the child nodes from 
    
      <Item>
            <A1>NA</A1>
            <A2>False</A2>
            <A3>02</A3>
            <A4>ER</A4>
          </Item>
    
  to
      <Item>
            <A2>NA</A2>
            <A4>False</A4>
            <A1>02</A1>
            <A3>ER</A3>
          </Item>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. I suggest you post a new question since it is not directly related to this one.